# How to exclude a string from parsed text file using Scala?

Tags: scala

A sample text file looks like this:

```
Date:  Nov 12, 2004
Support_Addresses:  Support@microsoft.com, suport@yahoo.com, 
                    google@gmail.com, 
                    support@comcast.net
Notes:  Need to renew support contracts for software and services.
```

Expected output is:

```
Nov 12, 2004
Support@microsoft.com, suport@yahoo.com, google@gmail.com, support@comcast.net 
Need to renew support contracts for software and services.
```

Basically, I need to exclude the field titles from the lines, so things like “Date:” , “Support_Addresses: “ and “Notes: “ are removed from the lines before they are saved to a CSV file. I have this code from other projects:

```
val support_agreements = lines
  .dropWhile(line => !line.startsWith("Support_Addresses: "))
  .takeWhile(line  => !line.startsWith(“Notes: "))
  .flatMap(_.split(","))
  .map(_.trim())
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .mkString(", ")
```

But it does not remove the field titles/names.  I am using `startsWith`, but it includes the field name. How can I exclude the field name from the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
text.lines.map{ line =>
  line.indexOf(':') match {
    case x if x > 0 =>
      line.substring(x + 1).trim
    case _ => line.trim
  }
}.mkString("\n")
```

it iterates through the lines and if it finds a colon it calls the substring function

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around with the code.  In the code, can the ':' be changed to "Support_Addresses:"  There maybe a : in other parts of the line, so I want to make sure I get the right string.  Like everything to the right of the "Support_Addresses:".

Comment: @SteveMcAffer, yes there is also another [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) that takes the whole string but beware that it returns position of the start, so you will need to change `x + 1` to something like `x + "Support_Addresses:".length`

Comment: It should only find the first colon of each line, isn't that enough?

Comment: Oh, OK.  Thanks for the information.  I will give this a try and get back to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. It builds a map of data `m` which could be manipulated usefully. This is then printed in the form you wanted.

```
def processValue(s: String): List[String] = 
  s.split(",").toList.map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)

val retros = lines.foldLeft(List.empty[(String, List[String])]) {
  case (acc, l) =>
    l.indexOf(':') match {
      case -1 => 
        acc match {
          case Nil => acc // ???
          case h :: t => (h._1, h._2 ++ processValue(l)) :: t
        }
      case n =>
        val key = l.substring(0, n).trim
        val value = processValue(l.substring(n+1))
        (key, value) :: acc
    }
}

val m = retros.reverse.toMap

m.values.map(_.mkString(", ")).foreach(println)
```